# TS2739 - Type missing in following properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

So i connect Typescript with hooks.
When i try to render Register User in parent component i getting error:

[image]

```
  interface IRegisterUser {
    mail: string;
    password: string;
  };

  let RegisterUser: React.FC<IRegisterUser> = (props) => {

    const InitialUserState = {mail: "", password: ""}
    const [user, setUser] = useState(InitialUserState)

    useEffect(() => {

    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
                <input type="text" className="text" name="username" value={user.mail}  placeholder="" required/>
                <input type="text" className="text" name="userpassword" value={user.password}  placeholder="" required/>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you expecting it to be an internal state or to be passed as prop?

Comment: You define `RegisterUser` as a component that requires `mail` and `password`, when yo use the component you don't provide `mail` and `password`. Either make tehse props optional or provide them on usage. This has nothing to do with hooks IMO

Comment: @Joseph Internal state - user should provide mail + password, later i create logic and API communication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comment:

> user should provide mail + password

The `RegisterUser` should **not** receive `mail` and `password` via props.

Make the `props` optional.

```
interface IRegisterUser {
  mail?: string;
  password?: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functional component `RegisterUser` requires props of type `IRegisterUser`. The `IRegisterUser` interface defines a mandatory `mail` and `password`.

TypeScript now shows an error (TS2739) because you are declaring `<RegisterUser/>` in your `<ModalBody>` without passing properties (`mail` and `password`) to it.

You can solve the error by declaring the following:

```
<ModalBody>
  <RegisterUser mail={''} password={''} />
</ModalBody>
```

Another option is to mark the properties as optional (see solution from Joseph D.) because you already initialize these properties in your `InitialUserState`.

You can see the solution for these kind of errors here: https://youtu.be/Uo3PFfjgoXo?t=580

Comment: Yes of course - but making this properties optional doesn't create not neccessary data flow between components :)